# s:text tag property name from request

Tags: struts2

I want to do something like this for my i18n,

```
<s:text name="#request.delements.get(positionId).element.i18n"></s:text>
```

But what get's printed is the value in the request object and not the corresponding proerty defined in the properties file.

Can this be achieved in any other way?

Regards,
Ayush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `%{}` notation inside `<s:text>` tag `name` attribute.

```
<s:text name="%{#request.delements.get(positionId).element.i18n}"></s:text>
```